# FedEx Api source code in vs c#

Tags: fedex

I downloaded the source code in FedEx web service.

I put all keys and password in the sample code and tested it.

I got a result display, but I don't know where the data is from.

Could you tell me where I can find the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The data is hard coded into the source code itself, putting the keys in is fine, but in that same file there should be hundreds of other lines that create the code which are hard coded on most of the api examples fedex uses.

Comment: So, I cannot see how the sample data uses inside, right? If then, can I apply for my own example in the code even though I use the sample code? Is the sample data removed if I use my own? Also, is it possible to apply for FedEx source code when I choose MVC 4 Web Application?

Comment: you should be able to see it in the sample solution you downloaded from fedex, if you run the sample program you should just be able to step through and see the data be populated, but yes if you pass your own object to the service then it should pass your object rather than the sample object

Comment: And in answer to your MVC question sure, you just add a service reference to your solution using the wsdl file, and you can then call that service from your solution

Comment: What you'are saying is that I can check where the sample data is from? If I click the debug, then only console windows is opened and shows the result. I tried to find how the data from a console window saves as well as the location, but I couldn't find it. Like you said, it is hard-coded. If so, how can I see the data be populated like you mentioned? I'm kind of confusing now.

Comment: I cannot use FedEx api attaching only c# files? Do I need to use WSDL files as well? In the sample code, I cannot find any WSDL category. How do I use WSDL??

Comment: the WSDL file is the definition for the service reference, it contains the classes and information that will be needed to create the reference to the fedex service, so no you will need to use this file when you create your service reference on your project file.

Comment: As for only seeing the console window come up put a break point in your program  after it loads, and you can then step through it line by line in the debugger

Comment: OK.. I see.. I checked it, but I want to know the location of the data. Even I used the break points, but the data is loaded all once, not step by step. the data that hard-coded is not visible?? My point is that how I can see the sample data location which is shown in the result window.

Comment: the data is not loaded all at once, or if it was there would be a massive block of highlighted text on the debugger, it might be populated by a function return, just step into the function when you get to it by hitting F11, and you should be able to step through the called functions

Comment: I set the break points and I went through it step by step, but numeral data was still displayed all at once. Are there any ways to check where and how the numeral data is stored?